# Is there any compatible version of kamon-prometheus dependency with scala 2.12.1?

Tags: scala, prometheus, kamon

I'm using [this](https://github.com/MonsantoCo/kamon-prometheus) reference.

Library Dependency is

```
"com.monsanto.arch" %% "kamon-prometheus" % "0.2.0"
```

I'm using scala version 2.12.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need Akka metrics in Prometheus format, maybe https://github.com/Workday/prometheus-akka will work for you.